# GSON implementation for amqp MessageConverter in SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gson, amqp

I am using a simple HelloWorld application to listen a JSON message in RabbitMQ Spring Boot application. I'd like to use/configure GSON Message Converter so that I can receive it as JSON mapped to java object.

For instance, if I want to use Jackson API for Json to Java conversion, I'll simply add the below configuration and my listener will make sure to convert the messages sent in JSON format to its corresponding POJO representation.

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter() {
return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

The below listener simply prints the message after unmarshalling into java object.

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "some.rabbitmq.queue")
public void receiveMessage(final CustomJavaPojo message) {
    log.info("Received message as specific CustomJavaPojo: {}", message.toString());
}
```

As I have used GSON for HTTP Message conversion in other part of the same application, I wanted to utilize the same gson library in messaging section of the application as well. However, I am unable to find any implementation that I can use.

I referred the [spring amqp converter package for various implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/package-summary.html) but didn't find any gson variation.

Is the only way to write my own GSON implementation of [MessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/MessageConverter.html) interface?

Or, as an alternative, I receive the message as a general purpose

```
@RabbitListener(queues = MessagingApplication.QUEUE_GENERIC_NAME)
public void receiveMessage(final Message message) {
    log.info("Received message as generic: {}", message.toString());
}
```

and then using `gson` to get java object from `json` string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
CustomJavaPojo result = gson.fromJson(json, CustomJavaPojo.class);
```

Similarly,for sending a message with the below `rabbitTemplate` configuration- , I will need the  `someImplementationOfGsonMessageConverter()` which doesn't seem to be available.

```
@Bean
public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory); 
rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(someImplementationOfGsonMessageConverter());
return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

So, I will not be able to use the below `convertAndSend` method

`rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(EXCHANGE, ROUTING_KEY, customJavaPojo);`

So, would you recommend that the other alternate approach available is to use

`rabbitTemplate.produce()` method instead and use `gson` to convert a pojo to json.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Implement your own or use the one from [this pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1863). It contains a JMS based one and a generic messaging one. The latter should be useable (using a [MessagingMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/MessagingMessageConverter.html) for you or at least adaptable to RabbitMQ.